# JQuery DOM manipulation: sum of 2 numbers generate NaN even if using parseInt()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple input type="number" on my page. They are dinamically generated each time a user clicks on a "add-form-row" button. I want to give as value to a `h2` element in my DOM based on the sum of each of these input each time a new input is added. When I try to sum the inputs, though, a NaN is returned. How can I fix this?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'elements');
        // here starts the sum logic
        var tot = 0;
        currentTotal = $('.form-row').find('input[type=number]').each(function() {
            numberPrice = parseInt($(this).val())
            tot += numberPrice
        });
        $('.totalPrice').text(`<span>${tot}</span>`)
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
   <input type="number" value="1">
   <input type="number" value="2">
   <button class="add-form-row">add</button>
   <div class="totalPrice"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code with no data isn't very helpful.  Supply sample HTML that contains some instances of `'input[type=number]'`

Comment: I am sorry, I added more details. I did not want to add too much since the html is generated with Django and I was afraid of going OT

Comment: Dude.  View source on the rendered page and copy and paste a couple of rows with values in them.  No one wants to wade through this.

Comment: I'm sorry. the code you edited is now similar to the one I have

Comment: Yeah, but since the code I edited is "working" it's obviously not similar enough I guess.  If I was going to guess, the issue is some artifact of the way JQuery's clone() works, assuming you're using that inside `cloneMore`

Comment: The code here seems to work fine. I put two numbers in, click the button and I see their sum, with no `NaN`s in sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the input value is `=""`, i.e nothing, the total will be `NaN`, because `parseInt("") = NaN`, so maybe adding a condition like this can solve your problem:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'elements');
        // here starts the sum logic
        var tot = 0;
        currentTotal = $('.form-row').find('input[type=number]').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() != ""){
                numberPrice = parseInt($(this).val());
                tot += numberPrice;
            }
        });
        $('.totalPrice').text(`<span>${tot}</span>`);
        return false;
    });
```